# Mockito: WebClient reactive method call

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, webclient, jacoco

I am facing difficulties in writing a unit test for my `collect`  method. Specifically, the Jacoco test coverage for the methods that occur after I call `getBearerToken()` within the `collectEndpointCount` method is not getting recognized. StepVerifier is able to verify that it has been completed but the values within it are all null.

Here is a quick breakdown of what my `collect` does. It takes in a `timeRange` and initiates 2 asynchronous operations using the `collectEndpointCount` method for each endpoint. This method retrieves an Apigee access token using `extractAccessToken` and `getBearerToken` to authenticate the API requests

The usage count data is fetched from the external API for each endpoint using the constructed URL and the obtained access token. The response is then processed by the `processEndpointResponse` method to extract the usage count. The collected counts for all 2 endpoints are combined using the Mono.zip operation.

**ResultsCollectorImpl.java**

```
public ResultCollectorImpl(WebClient webClient) {
    this.webClient = webClient;
}

@Override
public Mono<ResultStats> collect(String timeRange) {
    Mono<Long> results1 = collectEndpointCount(timeRange, "url1");
    Mono<Long> results2 = collectEndpointCount(timeRange, "url2");

    return Mono.zip(results1, results2)
        .map(tuple -> new ResultStats(tuple.getT1(), tuple.getT2()));
}

private Mono<String> getBearerToken() {
    return webClient.post()
        .uri("https://login.apigee.com/oauth/token")
        .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic ZWRnZWNsaTplZGdlY2xpc2VjcmV0")
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
        .bodyValue("grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=my_refresh_token")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String.class)
        .flatMap(this::extractAccessToken);
}

private Mono<String> extractAccessToken(String responseBody) {
    try {
        JsonNode accessTokenNode = new ObjectMapper().readTree(responseBody).get("access_token");
        if (accessTokenNode != null && accessTokenNode.isTextual()) {
            return Mono.just(accessTokenNode.asText());
        }
        return Mono.empty();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return Mono.error(e);
    }
}

private Mono<Long> collectEndpointCount(String timeRange, String url) {
    return getBearerToken()
        .flatMap(bearerToken -> webClient.get()
            .uri(url)
            .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + bearerToken)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .flatMap(responseBody -> Mono.fromCallable(() -> processEndpointResponse(responseBody))))
        .onErrorMap(ex -> ex instanceof WebClientResponseException || ex instanceof IOException,
            BillProcessorExceptionCollect::new);
}

private long processEndpointResponse(@NonNull String responseBody) throws IOException {
    try (JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonFactory().createParser(responseBody)) {
        while (jsonParser.nextToken() != null) {
            if (jsonParser.getCurrentToken() == JsonToken.FIELD_NAME
                && "values".equals(jsonParser.getCurrentName())) {
                jsonParser.nextToken();
                while (jsonParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
                    if (jsonParser.getCurrentToken() == JsonToken.VALUE_STRING) {
                        return (long) Double.parseDouble(jsonParser.getText());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**ResultsCollectorImplTest.java**

```
@Mock
private WebClient webClient;
@Mock
private ApigeeConfig apigeeConfig;
@InjectMocks
private ResultStatsCollectorImpl resultStatsCollector;
@Mock
private RequestBodyUriSpec requestBodyUriSpec;
@Mock
private RequestHeadersUriSpec requestHeadersUriSpec;
@Mock
private RequestHeadersSpec requestHeadersSpec;
@Mock
private ResponseSpec responseSpec;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    ResultStatsCollector = new ResultStatsCollectorImpl(webClient, apigeeConfig);
}

@Test
void testCollectWithValidData() {
    String timeRange = "08/01/2023 00:00~08/31/2023 23:59";

    Mono<String> accessToken = Mono.just("{\"access_token\":\"bearer_token\"");
    when(apigeeConfig.getRefreshToken()).thenReturn("mockRefreshToken");
    when(webClient.post()).thenReturn(requestBodyUriSpec);
    when(requestBodyUriSpec.uri(anyString())).thenReturn(requestBodyUriSpec);
    when(requestBodyUriSpec.header(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(requestBodyUriSpec);
    when(requestBodyUriSpec.bodyValue(anyString())).thenReturn(requestHeadersSpec);
    when(requestBodyUriSpec.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseSpec);
    when(responseSpec.bodyToMono(String.class)).thenReturn(accessToken);
    
    String mockApiResponse = "{\"from\":\"2023-08-01T00:00:00+08:00\",\" count1\":100,\"count2\":100}";
    when(webClient.get()).thenReturn(requestHeadersUriSpec);
    when(requestHeadersUriSpec.uri(anyString())).thenReturn(requestHeadersUriSpec);
    when(requestHeadersUriSpec.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "mockAccessToken")).thenReturn(requestHeadersSpec);
    when(requestHeadersSpec.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseSpec);
    when(responseSpec.bodyToMono(String.class)).thenReturn(Mono.just(mockApiResponse));

    Mono<ResultStats> usageStats = resultStatsCollector.collect(timeRange);

    StepVerifier.create(usageStats).verifyComplete();
}
```

[image: Jacoco Test Coverage]

Comment: Why do you assign `ResultStatsCollector`? It is never used. At the same time, `resultStatsCollector` is already assigned by annotation `@InjectMocks` (I'm assuming you are running the test with Mockito extension – your test class definition is not included in the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my method calls webClient, each produced a different `responseSpec`. Adding another mock ResponseSpec did the trick.

```
@Mock
private ResponseSpec responseSpecStats;


...
when(requestHeadersUriSpec.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseSpecStats);
when(responseSpecStats.bodyToMono(String.class)).thenReturn((endpointResponse));
```